# No se envia por submit mis datos de un formulario

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```css
    if(isset($_POST['actualizar_estudios'])){
        $respuesta=array(
            'mensaje'=>'hola'
        );
    }
```

Hola amigos estoy tratando que cuando se presione un boton de sumar esto llame un evento de tipo submit que me lleve uno datos a un controlador php:

```js
 function actualizarEstudios() {
         const sumar =$('#btn-sumar'),
             restar = $('#restar'),
             cant_estudios = Number($('#cantidad_estudio').val());

         sumar.submit(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
            console.log('hola');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'horas': cant_estudios
                },
                url: 'Controlador/usuario-controlador',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
                
            })
         });
    }
```

```html
<form action="Controlador/mes-controlador.php" id="btn-sumar" method="post" class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-5 ">
                            <input type="submit"  class="my-2 sumar btn btn-success" id="sumar" value="sumar">
                            <input type="hidden" name="sumar" value="<?php echo $estudios; ?>">
                        </form>
```

Bueno ahí tengo mi código. Me sale esto en la consola

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\wamp64\www\informe\Controlador\usuario-controlador.php:7:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
  'horas' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
</pre>
```

ya coloqué mi codigo php para que se pueda ver el controlador.

Comment: podrias poner el codigo de ``usuario-controlador``?

Comment: Hola ya hice el cambio